# How is In-App purchase of virtual currency banned but so widely used?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

At the bottom of the second page [Apple's In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) it says that virtual currency is not allowed to be sold through In-App purchases.  However, many games on the app store today sell "coins" or something similar that the user then spends on various upgrades or powers.  I am designing an app that should do something similar, but I obviously do not want it to get rejected.  Can anyone shed some light on this situation?  Also, if the items that are bought through the credit are non-consumable, will Apple host them?  And can I track which ones have been bought and how many times if they are bought through the credit?

Comment: All non-consumable items are persistent. You can keep track of your in-app purchases in the Sales and Trends section on your iTunesConnect account. Not sure about the virtual currency, but as there are a plenty of apps that use it, give it a try. Just make some more research in order to do it correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a great question. I think the virtual currency apps are like fart machines and flashlight apps: They were accepted into the store at first, but Apple eventually realized they didn't want that type of app on their store. So those apps that got accepted, they are still on the store, but from now on, no more.

As for your second and third questions, Apple isn't going to host any of the content of your game or app beyond what you can get into iCloud; they only record which things which people bought. So if someone bought 1000 coins 12 times, Apple will know that, but you have to keep track of how many coins the customer has left via iCloud or your own server.

**Update:** It looks like Apple will accept In-App purchase of virtual currency per the [Apple Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). Section 11.4 states:

> Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume
>   those credits within the application

So as long as the currency is redeemable within your application, it's fine. However, right in the introduction, it does say:

> We don't need any more Fart apps.

So fart apps are out, but virtual currency is OK!

Comment: The IAP guide says that Apple will host non-consumable products.  My products will be non-consumable, they will just be bought using the credit.  And I know that I can track the coin purchases, what I meant is can I track what was purchased using the coins? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: In that case, Apple will track who purchased your virtual coins, but you have to keep track of what was purchased in your app with virtual coins since that is part of your app and not part of the IAP system.

Comment: Fart apps are the single greatest thing that ever came out of the AppStore! Smurfberries are a close second.

Comment: @Garrett this was a while ago, but i'm in the same situation. were you allowed to have "non-consumable" products purchased using the consumable in-app purchases (by keeping track of purchases on your own server)?

Answer (score 1):

I think woz is right about how existing apps got there with virtual "coins", that they were submitted before Apple tightened the guidelines. Subsequent updates might get rejected. The main issue is that a virtual currency means you're able to alter the exchange rate, so a purchase of $5 worth of virtual coins could subsequently be devalued to $2 worth of virtual coins if the user doesn't redeem them in time. That's consistent with Apple's guideline that "it is important that users know the specific good or service they are buying."

As for tracking purchases of items, a non-consumable product is something that can only be purchased once: If the user tries to purchase it again, the store will tell you that the purchase succeeded, but it won't result in a second transaction. If you want something that can be purchased multiple times, then you need to track that yourself, and make it a consumable product.